# If field strength (magnitude) is: $E=kq/r^2 $, what happens at $r=0$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, singularities, coulombs-law

The formula for the Electric field strength (magnitude) is:

$$E=kq/r^2$$

where $k$ is a constant, $r$ is the distance from a point charge, and $q$ is the magnitude of the point charge. Given this there would be a singularity at $r=0$. How is this handled?  A singularity would occur for any power of $r$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the classical formula for field strength breaks down at $r=0$. This shows that the classical abstraction of a point particle is incorrect. Either the particle is not really a point particle because it has some internal structure - like the proton - or quantum mechanical effects come into play once $r$ gets small enough (or both).